# Complete Swift 4 Class description

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

All i found is the online documentation of Apple like:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation

And the documentation inside xcode9 which is probably the same like the online documentation.

But is there any more complete description of the Swift classes where ALL public methods and attributes etc are described?

Especially when it comes to macOS development it's not always easy to find all informations about the NS-classes. For iOS development there are a lot of books, youtube videos, etc.

And I think the meaning of stackoverflow is to find a solution for a specific problem and not to bother you with basic questions.

Thanks for any support about good resources or the right Apple link.

Comment: You say “Swift 4 Foundation” but these are two different things. There’s Swift and there’s Foundation. Foundation is not in Swift. And Swift is not Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple docs list all public parts of classes. They do only show what that class adds though so you may have to check out the protocols and superclass to see *everything*.

For example let's look at [`NSTableView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview):
The documentation for `NSTableView` lists all the properties and methods declared in that class.

It inherits from [`NSControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol) so there are more methods and properties listed there that you might need to look at. `NSControl` inherits from `NSView` which inherits from `NSResponder` which is a subclass of `NSObject`. That makes four additional documents that you may have to look in if you want to know about *every* method and property that is in a class.

In addition `NSTableView` conforms to eight protocols all of which potentially add things you may be interested in so you may have to look in those docs as well.

You might be wondering why you would hav etc look in so many places to find out about a single class. There are two reasons for this. First, The documentation for `NSTableView` would be *very* long if it listed *everything*. Second, Since most things in Foundation, AppKit, UIKit, etc have `NSObject` somewhere in their ancestry the properties and methods from it would be duplicated in a lot of documentation.

Over time you will find that you normally only need to go one, sometimes two, levels up to find the bits that matter to you at a given moment. Later you will find that you can guess what the property or method name is likely to have in it and use autocompletion to get whatever it is you are looking for.

Also, while there aren't as many resources for learning macOS programming as there are for iOS there are still several around including [Hacking with macOS](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/store/hacking-with-macos) by Paul Hudson.

Comment: "The Apple docs list all public parts of classes."  This is a safe claim, because "part" is not a well-defined term in Swift or Foundation!  Is *behavior* part of a class?  (I would say it is.)  Not all behavior is documented.  For example, many classes can throw exceptions, but don't document this fact.

Comment: If you are looking at the Swift version of the docs they do mention if they can throw an exceptions as they are marked with `throws`

Comment: theMikeSwan: No, Swift `throws` is for Errors, not Exceptions (which Swift has no syntax for).  The "Discussion" section sometimes mentions Exceptions, but often doesn't.

Comment: If you find a method that can throw an exception that isn't mentioned in the docs you should file a bug report. That is the only way the docs will get fixed, there are far too many docs for Apple to ever catch all the mistakes. Also given that the OP is talking about Swift it is unlikely they are referring to exceptions…

Comment: theMikeSwan: I've filed many such bug reports, over the past several years, and I haven't seen a single one ever get fixed.  That's not the only behavior absent from the docs, either.  And just because we're writing Swift doesn't mean we can ignore Foundation methods that can throw exceptions -- it just means it's harder to properly catch them.